# Matplotlib.pyplot - Multiple plots on a log-log plot the third plot will not show

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following handles the first two plots:

```
data = [228782,38376,1416068,15177,3267,37238,43946,16882,1032,18015,32867,99886,10837,539578,2097,243504,721254,821,7264,24889,11301229,45200,1489405,106374,86755,117564,1195884,35285,1,1,69718,49305,99705,755060,172177,90544,375,13231,41636,2194328,445222,4151167,16397,13233,16167,28013,23123,20600,279078,204561,903049,1077988,3175300,133098,313077,150900,7916,7192,27825,11757,131951,36491,412661,13770,234963,14,27165,2655993,35906,4726736,1400946,50211,970,12991,500415,49638,227901,113491,34705,3601896,13206,2,163363,1763238,704929,17683,3345746,6169795,50960,10562405,19964,8768,60654,36688,408987,5491596,9198,3555,6956,44754,24177,44582,961052,53915,136564,88098,2506,4963972,30797,182620,120865,255538,82780,62005,31621,1878092,9538,3,104934,190948,32669,144033,1476,10792,490043,44086,16947,65156,4,67559,91119,158176,41496,444282,716632,370458,3497,113392,14303,14122,29358,35527,3359,1283,49466,964715,2231204,222141,215161,295728,32342,13462,2479807,5400340,388405,67750,22347,1491,106668,1533418,535,10953,10796,286274,33799,68004,11507,84894,353376,963503,2450530,161553,146589,796,94487,124304,4909631,31693,7574328,321190,15335,243789,71551,4162413,292380,140728,611758,536,120032,549,32414,52314,3321,5251,17321,290913,224,138860,2175516,13886,3674482,308513,2179765,11830,2228414,128376,103459,100288,442028,2685164,176,2,821791,780,533,125481,140268,96293,223237,22322,51114,10292,126129,271666,104450,5073589,1767339,250,32306,154856,20439,2160830,5,310789,896015,754529,38198,1445987,12020931,795411,25003,538,36861,18150,991877,1962984,48752,82654,3963056,6494512,79644,12438,20884,7,3849311,1495,6469,291234,72614,5439,26130,274373,12597,811805,3,295383,99982,22564,38928,92,1907481,3075,729,658168,1165,951107,128879,680182,3601,4208,2026,108807,746024,2866765,1505305,344209,223629,121982,77107,20725,12501,6308,858843,3675204,5050872,152005,36862,238924,52329,2049905,29376,855373,3766990,1756,1516744,22267,1515269,616,10687,17424,30983,314870,5017553,110463,50482,34061,33543,107524,619803,1108,190765,108684,2452800,90389,3213,871491,3760,773869,63341,5691,23539,20696,36256,373034,8614,4724,3692,13870,105831,26373,3188,160035,27253,1281,3332,43168]

rank = sorted(list(range(1, len(data)+1)))
freq = np.array(sorted(data, reverse=True))
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.xlim(1, 10**3)
plt.ylim(1, 10**8)
lines = plt.loglog(rank, freq, marker=".")
plt.plot([1, freq[0]], [freq[0], 1], 'r')
```

Now I am trying to add this log-normal plot of:

```
    # log-normal
x = np.ma.log(freq)
avg = np.mean(x)
std = np.std(x)
pdf = lognorm.pdf(x, avg, 0, np.exp(std))
plt.loglog(pdf, x, marker='v')
# plt.plot(pdf, x, 'gv-')

title('Zipf plot of Airport frequency')
xlabel('frequency rank')
ylabel('airport frequency')
grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This is what produce by the both code blocks and as you can see the third plot is not showing:

[image]
Appreciate any insight on how to get this to work.  I running on Win10 using Python 3.7 with latest versions of matplotlib and other packages.

Comment: nice question, what have you done to find out why yourself? like put a label/legend in the plot to see if the 3rd dataset appears there? or do 3 seperate plots without limits to see where the data actually plots? or secure that you have not ended up in a state where there is no data to plot... or have you tried a switch to the `ax.plot` notation, should not make a difference but at least for me it feels better to be sure on what axis things are put. Happy hunting.

Comment: Have you printed `pdf`?

Comment: If you can post some of the data it will make it much easier for us to help, would it be possible to do that?

Comment: I posted the data that I am using.  I suspect I am not doing the log-normal correctly.  I tried different approaches no success so far.

Comment: `np.max(pdf)` = 0.0501.  `ylim` needs to be adusted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both plots are actually being plotted, but the x and y limits you're using are ignoring your log-normal data. I copied and ran your code exactly, except I changed the limits to

```
plt.xlim(10**-3, 10**3)
plt.ylim(10**-1, 10**8)
```

and this produced the plot below

[image]

When I want to adjust the x and y limits for my plots, I typically do that at the end right before `plt.show()` or when I define the `xlabel` and `ylabel`. I also will do `min(xdata)` and `max(xdata)` to get the limits that show all the data (you can also add offsets as necessary).

Comment: Yep my log-normal values are off and should be the same scale.